# Does route-me support route-finding?

Tags: iphone, ios, route-me

I would like to calculate a route along roads between two waypoints on a city map, as in the directions feature in Google Maps. Can I do this with route-me?

Comment: Not sure why I'm getting down-votes here. I've tried the route-me documentation, but the answer to my question isn't obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [asked](http://groups.google.com/group/route-me-map/browse_thread/thread/e663f82a32adb6b8) on the route-me mailing list in the end: the answer is no. The best bet is to use [CloudMade](http://cloudmade.com/), which is built on top of [route-me](https://github.com/route-me/route-me). However, the route-finding feature is unreliable. Also, to use CloudMade you must either pay them a per-user licence fee or host their adverts.